# Invoke docker container from Jenkins pipeline which is also running as docker container on Windows for docker (for Windows 10)

Tags: angularjs, windows, jenkins, docker, containers

I have installed docker for Windows on Windows 10. Pulled latest Jenkins image and start a container. Jenkins is started up and running.

In my Jenkins pipeline, I m building node application. I want to build this node application through Jenkins pipeline but within another container (docker container running from node and angular image) . I am new to docker and learning. Step by step help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to mount the docker socket into the Jenkins container, so that Jenkins can start docker containers by calling the docker engine running in the host machine (in your case a VM running on your Windows):

docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins:...

Comment: as such docker version is 1.13.1, it does not support docker.sock now. The only option which I can see is tcp in the jenkins docker container. But I dont know what changes I need to make and where. The reason is windows 10 will not have /var/run/docker.sock